# Vuetify - How to align rows in a v-treeview?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

New to Vue js, so please excuse me if its an ignorant question. I've searched all over and can't seem to figure this out.

I have a v-treeview with a folder structure, and descriptions of each folder in a 2nd column. I'm unable to get the Description column to align in the same row as the Browse column.

How can I get my 2nd column to align with the treeview?

My code is below:

```html
<v-layout>
  <v-flex xs12 sm4 justify-center>
    <h4>Browse</h4>
    <v-treeview
      v-model="selectedSelectableNodes"
      :items="rootStructure"
      item-key="path"
      item-text=""
      :search="search"
      :filter="customFilter"
      :open="open"
    >
    </v-treeview>
  </v-flex>

  <v-flex xs12 sm3 justify-center>
    <h4>Description</h4>
    <ul v-for="(item, i) in description" :key="i">
      <li><v-chip :color="colorCycle[(i+1) % 4]" outlined>{{ item }}</v-chip></li>
      <br/>
    </ul>
  </v-flex>
```

[image: Current Display]

Comment: Probably have to do with `lineHeight` not matching. Or some margin/padding.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to apply `.v-treeview-node__root` class to the `<ul>`, and `.v-treeview-node` to the `<li>` so they inherit the same styles as the TreeView nodes:

```html
<ul class="v-treeview-node__root" v-for="(item, i) in description" :key="i">
  <li class="v-treeview-node">
    <v-chip :color="colorCycle[(i + 1) % 4]" outlined>{{item}}</v-chip>
  </li>
  <br />
</ul>
```

[image]

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/aligning-adjacent-items-to-v-treeview-hggmg?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: The Descriptions show up even when the folder structure is not expanded out.

Comment: That logic isn't shown in your question, so I just assumed they're always visible, but the description visibility isn't relevant to the alignment issue. Did the applied classes work for you?